# Combine a queryset with a newly created object

Tags: django, django-queryset

There is a new object (not yet saved):

```
obj = MyObject()
q = MyObject.objects.all()
```

Is there any way to combine `obj` and `q`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can combine it with `chain`

Here I tried this in django shell:

```
In [1]: from itertools import chain
    ...: comment = Comment()
    ...: all_comments = Comment.objects.all()  # there's 1 comment in my db: <QuerySet [<Comment: Comment object>]>
    ...: combined = list(chain([comment], all_comments))
    ...: print(combined)
[<Comment: Comment object>, <Comment: Comment object>]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't combine if the `obj` is not saved(assuming you want to use the [queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/) here). here `q` is a lazy query. [When it is evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated), then it will bring all the objects including `obj` if its created before evaluation.

But You can append it to the list of objects after the `q` is evaluated(if you don't want to save `obj` no matter what). Like this:

```
q_list = list(q)
q_list.append(obj)
```